# Best way to convert keys in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mongodb, laravel

Im retrieving data from a mysql database like following Array:

```
$data = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 1, 
    'Benutzer' => 'foo', 
    'Passwort' => '123456', 
    'Adresse' => [
      'Strasse' => 'bla', 'Ort' => 'blubb'
    ],
    'Kommentare' => [
      0 => ['Titel' => 'bar', 'Text' => 'This is great dude!'],
      1 => ['Titel' => 'baz', 'Text' => 'Wow, awesome!']
    ]
  ],
]
```

Data like this shall be stored in a mongo database and therefore i want to replace the keynames with translated strings that come from a config- or languagefile ('Benutzer' -> 'username').

Do i really have to iterate over the array and replace the keys or is the a better way to achieve that?

Comment: There are other ways like using `array_combine` with `array_map` together, but trust me, it makes your code much more complicated and less readable compare to a simple foreach loop.

Comment: Yeah u're right. But this is for an import with a lot of records. So a foreach loop is extreme costly. Im already using `array_combine` and `array_map`. But it is hard to handle array values.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that doesn't iterate through all the array items at least once. Even php's array functions like `array_map` does that internally.

Comment: If your array is too big, you might want to break it into chunks and process each chunk separately. The best is to push each chunk into a queue and let the queuing system handle them in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate over the array then you can change the column name in the query itself using `select()` function.

Considering your model name is `Client` then your query will be:

```
Client::select('Benutzer as username', '...') // you can use `trnas()` function here also
      ->get()
```